# OneToMany relationship. How to make requests?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: My database structure]

Hello. I'm a noob in SQL so will appriciate if you help me write an SQL request to get FINALSCORE fields FROM tennisset table, related to tennismatch WHERE id = 1

Thanks.

Comment: You are not going to get any better if someone else writes the query for you.

Comment: I'm sure I will, just need to understend how to do it. Take the first step.

Comment: You should start with [SELECT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp) and continue with [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) Then come back with your code so far if you are still stuck. Please also read how to  prepare [mcve]

Comment: To simply JOIN tennismatch and tennisset tables, I would need the tennismatchID in the tennisset table. Here I'm dealing with OneToMany relationship and confused about the automatically generated table tennismatch_tennisset.

Comment: All I have come up with so far is getting the ids                                    SELECT mapOfSets_ID FROM tennismatch_tennisset WHERE TennisMatch_ID = 1;                                                                             but need the values.

Comment: Then you will continue to tenismatch table.

Comment: This could by your query `select * from tennismatch m join tenismatch_tennisset ms on m.id = ms.tennismatch_id join tennisset s on ms.mapofsets_id = s.id where m.id = 1`

Comment: You are not dealing with 1:n but m:n relationship. Because of it you have got generated intermediary table, that reduces it into two 1:n problems.

Comment: Big thanks, friend!

Comment: I have summarized it for you in an answer so you can mark it as solution and help others find answer easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select FINALSCORE from
tennismatch join
tennismatch_tennisset on tennismatch.ID = tennismatch_tennisset.TennisMatch_ID and tennismatch.ID = 1 join 
tennisset on tennismatch_tennisset.mapOfSets_ID = tennisset.ID
```

to delete the record from table "tennismatch", first delete the record from child table "tennismatch_tennisset".

Try something like this:

```
delete from tennismatch_tennisset where TennisMatch_ID =1 
delete from tennismatch where id=1
```

Comment: Can you help me with a statement to delete the row, please?

Comment: You want to delete the rows from which table?

Comment: I want to delete rows from tennismatch table

Answer (score 1):

You need to use join between tables. In your case it must be done through *tenismatch_tenisset* which is binding table between the two.

```
select finalscore from tennismatch m 
join tenismatch_tennisset ms 
    on m.id = ms.tennismatch_id 
join tennisset s 
    on ms.mapofsets_id = s.id 
where m.id = 1
```